# Mapping a list of tuples by tuple members

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a list of `decimal*decimal`

```
let tup = [(1M, 2M); (2M, 3M); (3M, 3M); (4M, 5M); (5M, 6M); (7M, 6M); (8M, 9M); (10M, 9M)]
```

I need a function that can group all of the values together if they can be connected, e.g.,

```
map[(100, [1M; 2M; 3M]); (101, [4M; 5M; 6M; 7M]); (102, [8M; 9M; 10M])]
```

I can't just do a `List.groupBy` because that misses anything else that may be connected "down the line" by another decimal value.  The `int` values in the map are arbitrary.  I'd like to be able to "seed" the starting value then increase each incrementally by some value.

What's the function look like that can do this?

Comment: As is, the question is pretty unclear. What is your definition of "connected"? Is Bartek's assumption correct that you want to find connected components of a graph? If that's the case, why are you working with decimals rather than integers?

Comment: In reality, they're `(billingID, shippingID)` and the exercise is trying to group customers together.  I wouldn't have thought of this as a graph problem, but then again, I'm new to graph theory.

Comment: In a given pair `(x, y)`, can `x` and `y` ever differ by more than `1M`? (They don't in your example data, but that could be happenstance.)

Comment: Yes, that's just happenstance of my example.  I'm looking at the [QuickGraph library](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/documentation) now in the hopes that I can find something suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I right that by 'connected' you mean that numbers represent nodes and tuples represent edges in undirected graph? As far as I know there is no function in standard library which would do that. You can search for some library that perform basic graph operations. The operation you want to perform is division to [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)).

You can also try to implement that function from the scratch.
Here is some [nice attempt](http://www.fssnip.net/av#Problem-88-Connected-components-alternative-solution).

Comment: This answer led me to the [`QuickGraph` library](https://quickgraph.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

*What* you're trying to accomplish seems to be adequately addressed already; as to *how* to accomplish it, here's one approach:

```
let groupConnected initId idTups =
    let mergeGroups projectIds input =
        (List.empty<SortedSet<_>>, input)
        ||> List.fold (fun groups x ->
            let ids = projectIds x
            match groups |> List.tryFind (fun g -> g.Overlaps ids) with
              | Some g -> g.UnionWith ids
                          groups
              | _      -> ids::groups)
    idTups
    |> mergeGroups (fun (a, b) -> SortedSet([| a; b |]))
    |> mergeGroups id
    |> List.sortBy (fun g -> g.Min)
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i g -> initId + i, List.ofSeq g)
    |> Map.ofSeq
```

Testing with this and your followup question's inputs:

> ```
> > groupConnected 100 [(1M, 2M); (2M, 3M); (3M, 3M); (4M, 5M); (5M, 6M); (7M, 6M);
>                       (8M, 9M); (10M, 9M)];;
> val it : Map<int,decimal list> =
>   map [(100, [1M; 2M; 3M]); (101, [4M; 5M; 6M; 7M]); (102, [8M; 9M; 10M])]
>
>
> > groupConnected 100 [(1M, 1M); (2M, 18M); (3M, 3M); (4M, 5M); (5M, 24M); (24M, 6M);
>                       (7M, 6M); (8M, 9M); (10M, 9M)];;
> val it : Map<int,decimal list> =
>   map
>     [(100, [1M]); (101, [2M; 18M]); (102, [3M]); (103, [4M; 5M; 6M; 7M; 24M]);
>      (104, [8M; 9M; 10M])]
> ```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/o67Dl9)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Here is one not very pretty solution:

```
let tup = [(1M, 2M); (2M, 3M); (3M, 3M); (4M, 5M); (5M, 6M); (7M, 6M); (8M, 9M); (10M, 9M)]

let findGroupings lst =
    let rec findGroup input previous acc =
        match input with
        | [] -> acc
        | (a,b)::t -> 
            match previous with
            | [] -> if a >= b then
                        findGroup t [] acc
                    else
                        findGroup t [b;a] acc
            | h::_ -> if a > h && a < b then
                        findGroup t (b::(a::previous)) acc
                      elif a > h && a >=b then
                        let full = List.rev (a::previous)
                        findGroup t [] (full::acc)
                      elif a >= b then
                        findGroup t [] ((List.rev previous)::acc)
                      elif a < h then
                        findGroup t [b;a] (previous::acc)
                      else // a = h and a < b
                        findGroup t (b::previous) acc
    findGroup lst [] []
    |> List.rev
```

Using

```
let result = findGroupings tup
```

gives

```
val result : decimal list list = [[1M; 2M; 3M]; [4M; 5M; 6M; 7M]; [8M; 9M; 10M]]
```

Comment: This fails with differently-sorted input, e.g. `[(1M, 2M); (3M, 3M); (4M, 5M); (7M, 6M); (8M, 9M); (10M, 9M); (5M, 6M); (2M, 3M)]`. ([Demo](https://ideone.com/NDLHr2))