# Getting connected components from a QuickGraph graph

Tags: c#, .net, f#, quickgraph

I'm new to graph theory.

I've created an adjacency graph with the [QuickGraph library](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) and ultimately, I'd like to have the connected components from the graph.

```
open QuickGraph

let tup = [(1M,1M); (2M, 18M); (3M, 3M); (4M, 5M); (5M, 24M); (24M, 6M); (7M, 6M); (8M, 9M); (10M, 9M)]

type Vertex = {decimal: decimal}

let edges = 
    tup
    |> List.map (fun x -> ({decimal = fst x}, {decimal = snd x}))
    |> List.map (fun x -> Edge<Vertex> x)

//Undirected Graph
let undirGraph = edges.ToUndirectedGraph()

undirGraph.Edges
undirGraph.Vertices

let x = QuickGraph.Algorithms.ConnectedComponents.ConnectedComponentsAlgorithm(undirGraph)
```

Output from `undirGraph.Edges`:

```
val it : Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Edge<Vertex>> =
seq
[FSI_0227+Vertex->FSI_0227+Vertex {Source = {decimal = 1M;};
                                       Target = {decimal = 1M;};};
 FSI_0227+Vertex->FSI_0227+Vertex {Source = {decimal = 2M;};
                                   Target = {decimal = 18M;};};
 FSI_0227+Vertex->FSI_0227+Vertex {Source = {decimal = 3M;};
                                   Target = {decimal = 3M;};};
 FSI_0227+Vertex->FSI_0227+Vertex {Source = {decimal = 4M;};
                                   Target = {decimal = 5M;};}; ...]
```

and from `undirGraph.Vertices`:

```
val it : Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Vertex> =
seq
[{decimal = 1M;}; {decimal = 2M;}; {decimal = 18M;}; {decimal = 3M;}; ...]
```

are as expected.

The undirected graph is created successfully, but now I'm stuck.  From here, I don't know how to get the connected components of the graph or, frankly, if I'm using the correct graph structure.

I would have expected `x` to contain the components in the graph but output from `x;;` in FSI looks like this:

[image: output from x in the FSI]

The values in the example `tuple list` represent `BillTo` and `ShipTo` customer ID values in a database.

The documentation in the QuickGraph library is sparse, particularly for someone trying to "learn on the fly."

*This question supplants a [previous question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396736/mapping-a-list-of-tuples-by-tuple-members).  I had considered modifying my prior question but, as this is a completely separate question, have decided to leave it as is.*

Comment: have you tried something else? igraph in R might do what you want and you can call it via the RProvider. It's probably also easier to actually graph what you need.

Comment: I have.  I can generate the graph and extract the connected components from `R`'s `iGraph` package fairly easily I had hoped to use `F#`.  It must be possible to do in `F#` and, given that the `QuickGraph` library already exists, it should be relatively simple.  I must be missing the solution.

Comment: Ah great. Can you show some screenshots and expected results for some simple data? I can just guess that most people who work with graphs don't use .NET. Btw I'm not really sure your graph is created correctly in the above case. you might need to open some other namespace in quickgraph maybe.

Comment: I adjusted the information in the question, including the fact that I converted a graph to an undirected graph which can be passed to `Algorithms.ConnectedComponents.ConnectedComponentsAlgorithm()` and included a screenshot of the output.  I can generate the connected components list in `R` with `igraph` very easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that you need to call the `Compute` method on the algorithm to actually get it to run!

I took your sample code and just added call to `Compute`:

```
let x = QuickGraph.Algorithms.ConnectedComponents.
          ConnectedComponentsAlgorithm(undirGraph)
x.Compute()
```

Once you do this, `x.Components` contains a dictionary that assigns an index of a component to each vertex, so if you want groups of vertices (representing components), you can just group the results by the `Value` (which is the component index):

```
x.Components 
|> Seq.groupBy (fun kv -> kv.Value)
|> Seq.map (fun (comp, vertices) -> 
    comp, vertices |> Seq.map (fun kv -> kv.Key))
```

This gives the following:

```
[ (0, [{decimal = 1M;}]); 
  (1, [{decimal = 2M;}; {decimal = 18M;}]);
  (2, [{decimal = 3M;}]);
  (3, [{decimal = 4M;}; {decimal = 5M;}; {decimal = 24M;}; 
       {decimal = 6M;}; {decimal = 7M;}]);
  (4, [{decimal = 8M;}; {decimal = 9M;}; {decimal = 10M;}]) ]
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @s952163 Would you be too upset if I switched my accepted answer to this one?  This is really the answer to my original question!

Comment: @Steven of course not. It's your Q after all! And that was the whole point of the bounty. If you can, please do so! ;-) Was about to suggest it myself.

Answer (score 6):

Is this something you are looking for?

[image: Graph]

I would use use the RProvider to send the code to R and generate this and then wrap it in a dll if necessary. You can then use `components`, `clusters`, `groups` etc. to extract the connections.

```
# In R:
g1 <- graph(  edges=c( "1","1", "2", "18", "3", "3", "4", "5", "5", "24", "24", "6", "7", "6", "8", "9", "10", "9"),n=9,directed=T)
plot(g1)
comp1 <- components(g1)
comp1
groups(comp1)
cl <- clusters(g1)
lapply(seq_along(cl$csize)[cl$csize > 1], function(x) 
  V(g1)$name[cl$membership %in% x])
```

In case you decide to still stick to QuickGraph, what you are seeing in FSI is because you are defining a record type called `Vertex` that has one member called decimal of type decimal. This is a tad bit confusing, so initially I would suggest you stick to `int` and just generate the graph the following way:

```
let tup = [(1,1); (2, 18); (3, 3); (4, 5); (5, 24); (24, 6); (7, 6); (8, 9); (10, 9)]
let edges =
    tup |> List.map (fun x -> SEdge<int>(fst x, snd x))
let graph = edges.ToAdjacencyGraph()
let uniGraph = edges.ToUndirectedGraph()
```

You could also just write some sort of dictionary like data structure that keeps record/count of the references.

Comment: Independent of this answer, this is what I ended up doing: just sending everything to `igraph` through `RProvider`.  I don't think it's an idea solution but it works for now.  Future me needs to spend more time in `QuickGraph` and with graph theory.